# Problem creating Windows forms in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I want to build a Windows application through Windows forms.
What I want to do is create a new form and connect this form to the original form and transfer the data between the two.
But there is a big problem.
**When I create a new form, it copies everything in the original form and puts a lock icon on them and nothing can be changed**. Everything I do in the original form is copied in the new form and if the form I get a new run The main form runs
Only the original form design is copied to the new form, not the code. The new form codes are completely empty.
what is the problem?
thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcYRm.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click and unlock object.